# Not able to load and render Layout

Tags: magento-1.9

**I have a module Ggk/Madhav in app/code/local
In that controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Ggk_Madhav_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
       echo "Hii";
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
   }
   public function mamethodeAction()
   {
     echo 'test mamethode';
    }
}

**In etc/config.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ggk_Madhav>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ggk_Madhav>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <madhav>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ggk_Madhav</module>
                    <frontName>madhav</frontName>
                </args>
            </madhav>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <madhav>
                    <file>madhav.xml</file>
                </madhav>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <ggk_madhav>
                <class>Ggk_Madhav_Block</class>
            </ggk_madhav>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>

**In Block/home.php**

<?php

class Ggk_Madhav_Block_Home extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
     public function methodblock()
     {
         return "informations de mon block !!" ;
     }
}


**In app/design/frontend/ggk/default/layout/madhav.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <madhav_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="madhav/home"  name="madhav" template="ggk_madhav/home.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </madhav_index_index>
</layout>

**In app/design/frontend/ggk/default/template/ggk_madhav/home.phtml**

<?php
echo $this->methodblock();
?>
```

I am nota ble to render the layout madhav.xml 
So please suggest me the solution for not rendering the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested your code yet but seems that the problem is in your layout file.

You have defined the block in the config.xml like:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <ggk_madhav>
            <class>Ggk_Madhav_Block</class>
        </ggk_madhav>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

but you are calling the phtml file using:

```
<block type="madhav/home" name="madhav" template="ggk_madhav/home.phtml" />
```

which should be:

```
<block type="ggk_madhav/home" name="madhav" template="ggk_madhav/home.phtml" />
```

Please check and let me know if the problem still exists.

**Update:** I checked and corrected above line in your code and its working fine here.

Screenshot attached for reference.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: No It's not working.

Comment: @madhavbypureddy, please check my screenshot.

Comment: @madhavbypureddy, Can you please upvote if my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...Working for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <madhav_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="ggk_madhav/home"  name="madhav" template="ggk_madhav/home.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </madhav_index_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: No It's not working for me. Can u share me the screenshot of yours?